# Android: How to set Imagevisibility using intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an activity with a list view and a common header with  hidden icon..
when I click the listview a loginscreen will be triggered
and when the login is successfull it should come back to previous activity
with icon visible on header. I'm using a static image initially to hide the icon when the user comes to that particular screen. below is my login code

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    if(password.equals("guest")){
        returnIntent.putExtra("result", true);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);     
    } 
    else {
        returnIntent.putExtra("result", false);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
    }

    finish();                  
}
```

below is my `onActivityResult()` code

```
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    boolean success = data.getBooleanExtra("result", false);
    if(success) {
        sImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        sImg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

`sImg` is a static image. Above code seems ok for me but not working.

Comment: How do you start your login activity?

Comment: the code seems okay. to find the reason better put some log. one in the onclick print the password. another in onactivityresult printing success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

itz working with below code..but not sure whether itz a correctway

```
if(success) {
            img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.redeye);
            sImg = img;
            img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
}}
```